# Bash script trouble interpretting input

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I wrote a bash script that uploads a file on my home server. It gets activated from a folder action script using applescript. The setup is the folder on my desktop is called place_on_server. Its supposed to have an internal file structure exactly like the folder I want to write to: /var/www/media/
usage goes something like this:

- if directory etc added to place_on_server: ./upload DIR etc
- if directory of directory:  etc/movies ./upload DIR etc movies //and so on
- if file to place_on_server: ./upload F file.txt
- if file in file in place_on_server ./upload F etc file.txt //and so on

for creating a directory its supposed to execute a command like:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1<<EOF
cd /var/www/media/wherever
mkdir newdirectory
EOF
```

and for file placement:

```
rsync -rsh='ssh -p22' file  root@192.168.1.1:/var/www/media/wherever
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
addr=$(ifconfig -a | ./test)
if ($# -le "1")
then
    exit
elif ($1 -eq "DIR")
then
    f1="ssh -b root@$addr<<EOF"
    list = "cd /var/www/media\n"
    if($# -eq "2")
    then
        list=list+"mkdir $2\nEOF\n"
    else
        num=2
        i=$(($num))
        while($num < $#)
        do
            i=$(($num))
            list=list+"mkdir $i\n"
            list=list+"cd $i\n"
            $num=$num+1
        done
    fi
    echo $list
elif ($1 -eq "F")
then
    #list = "cd /var/www/media\n"
    f2="rsync -rsh=\'ssh -p22\' "
    f3 = "root@$addr:/var/www/media"
    if($# -eq "2")
    then
        f2=f2+$2+" "+f3
    else
        num=3
        i=$(($num))
        while($num < $#)
        do
            i=$(($num))
            f2=f2+"/"+$i
            $num=$num+1
        done
        i=$(($num))
        f2=f2+$i+" "+$f3
    fi
    echo $f2
fi
exit
```

output:

```
(prompt)$ ./upload2 F SO test.txt
./upload2: line 3: 3: command not found
./upload2: line 6: F: command not found
./upload2: line 25: F: command not found
```

So as you can see I'm having issues handling input. Its been awhile since I've done bash. And it was never extensive to begin with. Looking for a solution to my problem but also suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For comparisons, use `[[ .. ]]`. `( .. )`  is for running commands in subshells
2. Don't use `-eq` for string comparisons, use `=`.
3. Don't use `<` for numerical comparisons, use `-lt`
4. To append values, `f2="$f2$i $f3"`
5. To add line feeds, use `$'\n'` outside of double quotes, or a literal linefeed inside of them.
6. You always need "$" on variables in strings to reference them, otherwise you get the literal string.
7. You can't use spaces around the `=` in assignments
8. You can't use `$` before the variable name in assignments
9. To do arithmetics, use `$((..))`: `result=$((var1+var2))`
10. For indirect reference, such as getting `$4` for `n=4`, use `${!n}`
11. To prevent word splitting removing your line feeds, double quote variables such as in `echo "$line"`

Consider writing smaller programs and checking that they work before building out.

Here is how I would have written your script (slightly lacking in parameter checking):

```
#!/bin/bash
addr=$(ifconfig -a | ./test)
if [[ $1 = "DIR" ]]
then
  shift
  ( IFS=/; echo ssh "root@$addr" mkdir -p "/var/www/media/$*"; )
elif [[ $1 = "F" ]]
then
  shift
  last=$#
  file=${!last}
  ( IFS=/; echo rsync "$file" "root@$addr:/var/www/media/$*" )
else
  echo "Unknown command '$1'"
fi
```

`$*` gives you all parameters separated by the first character in `$IFS`, and I used that to build the paths. Here's the output:

```
$ ./scriptname DIR a b c d
ssh root@somehost mkdir -p /var/www/media/a/b/c/d
$ ./scriptname F a b c d somefile.txt
rsync somefile.txt root@somehost:/var/www/media/a/b/c/d/somefile.txt
```

Remove the echos to actually execute.

Comment: Thank you sir. The reason for the long delay in response is b/c I tried to do the noble thing and edit my own script to work, but I can't quite figure out how ssh@host<<EOF is supposed to work in a bash script so I went with what you have. I think your response is going to help a lot of bash noobs looking for answers.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your script are the conditional statements, such as

```
if ($# -le "1")
```

Despite what this would do in other languages, in Bash this is essentially saying, execute the command line `$# -le "1"` in a subshell, and use its exit status as condition.

- in your case, that expands to `3 -le "1"`, but the command `3` does not exist, which causes the error message

  > ./upload2: line 3: 3: command not found

The closest valid syntax would be

```
if [ $# -le 1 ]
```

---

That is the main problem, there are other problems detailed and addressed in [that other guy's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17204159/1743811).

One last thing, when you're assigning value to a variable, e.g.

```
f3 = "root@$addr:/var/www/media"
```

don't leave space around the `=`. The statement above would be interpreted as "run command `f3` with `=` and `"root@$addr:/var/www/media"` as arguments".